# Проблема с выпадающими списками

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Кнопка добавления дел//
  $('#deal-add-button').on("click",function(){
    var name = $('#name-text').val();
    var desc = $('#description-text').val();
    //Проверка заполнения полей//
    if (!name){
      alert('Заполните поле "Название"!');
      return false;
    }
    if (!desc){
      alert('Заполните поле "Описание"!');
      return false;
    }
    //Создание и помещение информации в html документ//
    var s = '';
    s += '<div class = "deal-column">';
    s += '<div class = "deal-name">' + name + '<button class = "close-button"><img src = "img/close.png"></button>' + '<button class = "arrow"><img src = "img/arrow.png"></button>' + '</div>';
    s += '<div class = "deal-desc">' + desc + '</div>';
    s += '</div>';
    if ($('#deals').length){
      $('#deals').remove();
    }
    $('#left-column').append(s);
    $('#name-text').val('');
    $('#description-text').val('');
     
     //Кнопка удаления дел//
    $('.close-button').on('click',function(){
      $(this).closest('.deal-column').remove();
      if (!$('#deals').length && !$('.deal-column').length){
        var p = '';
        p += '<div id = "deals">Список пуст...</div>';
        $('#left-column').append(p);
      };
    });

    $('.arrow').on('click',function(){

      $(this).closest('.deal-column').find('.deal-desc').slideToggle();
      
      $(this).toggleClass('rotation');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 font-family:Arial;
}

#parent {
 margin-top: 60px;
 margin-bottom: 150px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 980px;
 height: 560px;
 
 
 
}

#left-column{
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 height: 560px;
 width: 470px;
 font-size: 20px;
 float:left;
}

   #deals{
    position: relative;
    font-size:14px;
    color: #c6cad5;
    margin-top: 50px;
   }


   .deal-column{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 450px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;

   }

#right-column{
   position: relative;
   width: 470px;
   height: 560px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;

}
     #deal-form{
      margin-top: 30px;
      height: 520px;
      width: 470px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: white;
     }
       #deal-name{
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#8a94af;

       }
          #name-text{
           margin-top: 10px;
           display: block;
           position: relative;
           border-color:#ebebeb;
           width: 390px;
           height: 28px;
           resize: none;
           font-size: 18px;
           padding: 10px;
          }

       #deal-description{
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 30px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        color: #8a94af;
        font-size: 14px;
       }  
          #description-text{
           margin-top: 10px;
           display: block;
           position: relative;
           border-color:#ebebeb;
           width: 390px;
           height: 220px;
           resize: none;
           font-size:18px;
           padding: 10px;
          }

       #deal-add-button{
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 30px;
       margin-bottom: 20px;
        margin-left: 40px;
        height: 55px;
        width: 245px;
        border:none;
        background-color: #2174fe;
        color: white;
        font-size:18px;
       }

       .deal-name{
        padding:15px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
        font-size: 16px;

       }
       .deal-desc{
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
        padding:15px;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #889186;

       }
       .close-button{
        margin-left: 10px;
         height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border:none;
        background-color: white;
       }
       .arrow{
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border:none;
        background-color: white;
        float:right;
       }
       .arrow2{
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        border:none;
        background-color: white;
        float:right;
       }
       .rotation{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <title>Список дел</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src = "jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "parent">
     <div id = "left-column">Список дел:
        <div id = "deals">Список пуст...</div>
     </div>
     <div id = "right-column">Добавить новое дело
        <div id = "deal-form">
         <div id = "deal-name">*&nbsp;&nbsp;Название
          <textarea id = "name-text" maxlength="35"></textarea>
         </div>
         <div id = "deal-description">*&nbsp;&nbsp;Описание
          <textarea id = "description-text" maxlength="120"></textarea>
         </div>
         <button id = "deal-add-button" >Добавить дело</button>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#left-column').on("click", ".arrow", function(){
    $(this).closest('.deal-column').find('.deal-desc').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('rotation');
  });
  ...


  // убрать: $('.arrow').on('click',function(){

});
```

Аналогично - для `$('.close-button').on('click',`.